# How do I show right-aligned text in a WPF DataGrid column that is truncated on the left side instead of the right?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to show right-aligned text in a DataGrid column that is truncated on the left side if the column is to small. The right part always has to be visible.
I tried the following xaml without success - it still truncates the right side. What am I doing wrong?

It would be even better if I could use a RadGridView from Telerik. The problem there is the same and the example is shorter with standard components...

main window:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
                {
                    "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1",
                    "y yyyyyyyyyyyy   yyy      yyyyyy       yyyyy2"
                };

                this.DataContext = this;
            }
        }
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Right" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think you should use line wrapping instead. It's a common technique for data tables. I think Excel is doing the same. You can limit the number of lines to prevent an excessive row height. This will make usually a scroll bar appear to allow scrolling to the hidden lines. For example, allow three lines before clipping succeeding lines using a scroll bar.

Comment: Line wrapping is not an option. A have to show a tree / a path where the element on the right side is the one that really matters. I have no Excel available at the moment but Libre Calc does exactly what I need - right aligned text is truncated left. That's the only logical thing to do.